# Не удается запустить двойную команду консоли с разделителем && в QProcess PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.8, qprocess

Подскажите пожалуйста с чем может быть связана эта проблема: мне не удается запустить двойную команду консоли с разделителем && в QProcess PyQt5, программа просто ничего не делает. Вот часть кода в Python:

```
...
self.procedure_1 = QProcess()
input_file = "/run/media/helg/WDC/Image.iso"
output_folder = "/run/media/helg/WDC/"
preset = "sacd_extract -2 -p -c -i"
cmd = f'cd "{output_folder}" && {preset} "{input_file}" '
self.procedure_1.start(cmd)
...
```

Если запустить эту строку в терминале (без Python), то всё работает. Вот полный вид строки в терминале:

```
$ cd "/run/media/helg/WDC/" && sacd_extract -2 -p -c -i "/run/media/helg/WDC/Image.iso"
```

Comment: Скорее всего что то неправильно с путем  "/run/media/helg/WDC/" или правами текущего пользователя. Вторая часть после && выполняется только если первая закончилась успешно. А, первая похоже, не закончилась. Это единственное разумное объяснение

Comment: Нет, если по отдельности вызывать эти команды, то ошибок нет, но это не выход из положения, т.к. при каждом новом запуске Qprocess не будет сохранять путь после команды "cd". Теперь у меня сомнения, что QProcess в принципе поддерживает такую запись двойной команды.

Comment: Я думал речь идет о шелле. Невнимательно прочитал. Это вообще в корне неверный подход, запускать такие команды как отдельные процессы. Они точно не поддерживаются ничем многопроцессорным. Вам нужно явно указать путь для выходного файла и тогда проблема переходить в рабочую папку отпадет сама собой

Comment: Я бы указал, но эта утилита sacd_extract не имеет таких опций, поэтому приходится искать обходные пути, так бы конечно задал выходную папку и всё. Не получается.

Comment: Можно перефразировать вопрос так: как указать выходную папку для консольной утилиты в терминале, если консольная утилита  не поддерживает явного указания выходной папки (без  использования команды cd).